# How to use ODataQueryOptions in case of TypeLess (UnTyped) object in ASP.NET WebApi / OData project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have been referring **Asp.net WebApi 2.2** support for **OData**. It is very interesting where WebApi handles lot of **OData V4** protocol related things.

I need to implement an Odata service where I dont have CLR object. I get to know about properties of my class at runtime. Its like I have xml files which store Sql queries. I read those xml files and execute the queries in them. After reading the XML file I realize the columns and would like expose this information under OData service.

Challenge I have been facing is that I am not able to apply **ODataQueryOptions** on **untyped (non CLR)** objects.

Sample code https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataUntypedSample/ReadMe.txt shows how to expose untyped object from WebApi OData service but it does not show how to apply ODataQueryOptions.

```cs
public class ProductsController : ODataController
  {
    private static IQueryable<IEdmEntityObject> Products = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(i =>
    {
      IEdmEntityType productType = (IEdmEntityType)ODataUntypedModel.Model.FindType("AnalyticsPortal.Product");

      EdmEntityObject product = new EdmEntityObject(productType);
      product.TrySetPropertyValue("Id", i);
      product.TrySetPropertyValue("Name", "Product " + i);
      product.TrySetPropertyValue("Price", i + 0.01);
      product.TrySetPropertyValue("Category", "Category - " + i);

      return product;
    }).AsQueryable();

    ///*
    public EdmEntityObjectCollection Get()
    {


      //return productsContext.Products.AsQueryable();

      var path = Request.ODataProperties().Path;
      var edmType = path.EdmType;
      var collectionType = edmType as IEdmCollectionType;
      var entityType = collectionType.ElementType.Definition as IEdmEntityType;
      var model = Request.ODataProperties().Model;
      var queryContext = new ODataQueryContext(model, entityType, path);
      var queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, Request);



      //Apply the query option on the IQueryable here.
      //queryOptions
      //How ??
      //queryOptions.ApplyTo() work only on CLR types

      //IQueryable<IEdmEntityObject>

      return new EdmEntityObjectCollection(new EdmCollectionTypeReference(collectionType), Products.ToList());
    }
    //*/
  }
```

I would appreciate if someone can point me to a way where some framework or plugin can handle OData query options (filter, select, order etc...)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem ? I'm currently facing the same issue.

Comment: @Arun

Unfortunately not. I used WCF (Data services) project to implement above requirement.

Comment: if someone is still interested.. check the following: [Invoking Query Options Directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#invoking-query-options-directly)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you have to apply them yourself. OData will only apply them for you if you expose an IQueryable of a concrete type (typically through EF) but if you don't have that then it won't know how to apply it as you could be getting your data from anywhere!

Comment: Your response is on similar lines on information I have gathered. However I dont think getting data from anywhere is an issue here. I can get my data from sql query and build a IQueryable<IEdmEntityObject>. Issue is that ODataQueryOptions only applied to CLR types

Comment: I thought that you were trying to apply the filters at a database level. Am I right in thinking that you are returning a list and you want OData to post filter it? If so, can you post the code from your controller please?

Comment: Hi Tom, I have added code in my original question itself.

Comment: What happens if you add the [EnableQuery] attribute to the method?

Comment: I cant as I am not returning IQueryable<T>. If I return IQueryable<T> then I get exception saying that Odataformatter does not know how to serialize...

As mentioned in my question. Sample code is present at https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataUntypedSample/ReadMe.txt

Comment: I think that brings us full circle then. Without the attribute, OData won't apply the query options and if you can't add the attribute then you have to apply them yourself. Sorry!